# How to go some pixels down from the "id" when you clicked an option in a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code is an option from the menu bar of the web page that Im designing.

`<li class="about"><a href="#about">Nosotros</a></li>`

After I clicked the option, I want that it goes X pixels down from the `id=about` that it will go.

How can I do that? Im a beginner and I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please refer to this page:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you wanted the page to scroll to 50px below the top of the element, you could do something like this:

```
$("li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var targetElement = $($(this).attr('href')); // select the element by grabbing the href of the clicked link
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: targetElement.offset().top + 50
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sorry at the same time because Im getting familiar with HTML5/CSS, how do I integrate that to my HTML code? Thanks.

Comment: You need to include jQuery right before your closing body tag. Following that, include the above code in a <script> tag. Do some research about including jQuery on a page.

Comment: Ok, thanks by the way, I will do some research.

Comment: I do this before the body closing tag, but it not works
`<script>
$("li a").click(function() {
var targetElement = $($(this).attr('href'));
$('html, body').animate({
scrollTop: targetElement.offset().top + 200}, 2000);
});
</script>`

Comment: Check the developer console and see what error(s) you are getting. Did you include jQuery?

Comment: Also, see the updated code to prevent the default behavior of the link.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution without JavaScript:

The Position you want to jump to:

```
<a class="anchor" id="about_jump"></a>
<div id="about">
    ... 
</div>

.anchor{
    display: block; 
    position: relative; 
    top: +50px; 
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

The Link:

```
<li class="about"><a href="#about_jump">Nosotros</a></li>
```